# Protobuf-net : Nested IEnumerable objects

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am using Protobuf-net to serialize a custom nested list. I understand that native lists cannot be nested directly, which is why I have used a container object for the inner list. However, I would also like to make my container objects IEnumerable but this means Protobuf-net throws it out with the error:

> Nested or jagged lists and arrays are not supported

Here is an example of my list structure which causes the error:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyOuterList<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    readonly List<MyInnerList<T>> nestedData = new List<ObjectList<T>>();
}

[ProtoContract]
public class MyInnerList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private readonly List<T> data = new List<T>();
}
```

The fix is to remove IEnumerable from `MyInnerList` but obviously that prevents it being directly iterable. Is there a sneaky attribute like `[ProtobufCustomObjectSoPleaseIgnoreIEnumerable]` that could be used?

The best alternative I have come up with so far is to use an Enumerable property as shown below but I fear that the property could still be cast back to a list again. I would prefer to be using `GetEnumerator/yield` in some way but I can't see how.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyInnerList<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private readonly List<T> data = new List<T>();

    public IEnumerable<T> Data
    {
        get { return this.data; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a sneaky attribute like `[ProtobufCustomObjectSoPleaseIgnoreIEnumerable]` that could be used?

yup:

```
[ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling=true)]
public class MyInnerList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private readonly List<T> data = new List<T>();
}
```

sneaky is sneaky. `IgnoreListHandling` has the intellisense documentation:

> If specified, do NOT treat this type as a list, even if it looks like one.

Also, due to multiple requests [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413832/protobuf-net-jagged-multidim-arrays-surrogate-wrapper-etc-one-more-time), I plan on looking at implementing support for jagged arrays / lists shortly. The plan is to basically get the runtime to spoof the wrapper with a member (field 1) in the serializer's imagination, so you can use `List<List<T>>` and it'll work just like your model above (it will even be wire-compatible, since you sensibly chose field `1`).

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. I didn't know quite where I should be looking.

Comment: Still having problems getting this to work. Issue posted here: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=287&q=IgnoreListHandling

Comment: @shakinfree k; will take a look

Comment: Is there a way to inject this onto a class generated from a .proto file?  I have a partial class extension fragment that adds IEnumerable onto such a class but I can't add `ProtoContract` there as it is already present in the generated code.

Comment: @Miral not via an attribute, but you could use var metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Add(type, false) and then configure the metaType...

Comment: The exception is still there. Is there a plan to overcome this limitation?