# What is the significance of Protobuf "field 1"?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to figure out how to encode a byte[][] jagged array in Protobuf.

In my searching I haven't been able to see how to achieve this, but I do see [hints of a future feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16459279/328397) implementation that encode this in field 1.

What is the benefit of Field 1 and how is it applicable to Protobuf?

Answer (score 0):

There is no special significance to field 1, except that it is the first field, and thus the most obvious field number to use in a single-field message format. In the answer you linked, Marc seems to be saying that he's considering adding built-in support for "jagged arrays" that will be encoded as a list-of-messages where each message contains another list. The inner lists have field number 1 simply because that's the obvious number to choose. So, if you manually define such a type using field number 1 for the inner lists today, you will be able to switch over to Marc's built-in type later on without breaking backwards compatibility.