# Creating .proto file for List of List<int> and serialize the json into object not working in C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I am creating a simple POC application to check how protobuff works, In order to test with List of List because our actual application contains the 2D array property in class.

I am having a hard time to defining the proper .proto file so when the protobuff compile the cs file it serialize properly into my object.

Can someone help me to define the proper .proto file for it?

My C# Class

```
public class Root
    {
        public List<List<int>> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

My .proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";  


message Root
{
   repeated Outer Data=3;
}   
message Outer {
    repeated Inner Out=1;
}

message Inner {
     int32 Inn=1;
}

 var serialzeObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>("{'Data':[[1, 2],[3, 4]]}");
```

It parses the JSON but with an empty object.

Any help in this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you considered protobuf .net ? I find the code-first approach easier to use.

Comment: @JonasH , Thank you, Actually, I saw that package as well, But again it doesn't have support for Jagged array or a nested list.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Protobuf-net : Nested IEnumerable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459227/protobuf-net-nested-ienumerable-objects)